# How can I create a filename using bash command parameter?

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to create a filename using command param as such but not sure how to go about doing it. This is what I was trying:

```
echo "AZ" |xargs date >> $1.txt
```

I'm trying to create a file named AZ.txt with the date in it.

Comment: Are you trying to write the date to a file named `AZ.txt`, or `AZ` to a file named `2020-06-17.txt`, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to write filename AZ.txt

Comment: Is `date >> AZ.txt` what you are looking for? I didn't understand where the parameter whould be used

Comment: To be clear, with the code here, the `>> $1.txt` happens **before** `xargs` is started. It's not an argument to `xargs`, it's an instruction to the shell that runs xargs to redirect the output of `xargs` somewhere. `xargs` never sees it and can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use xargs, then you'll have to wrap the rest of it in a shell script to delay execution of the redirection until you have constructed the filename:

```sh
echo AZ | xargs sh -c 'date >> "$1".txt' sh
```

The trailing "sh" is to force the xargs argument "AZ" into $1 instead of $0

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the file comes from some command, you can use command substitution:

```
date > "$(echo AZ)".txt
```